# How to gray out part fo surf plane on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, surf

The MATLAB code below is used to plot a plane and show constrain lines on the same plane.
The constrained areas are as below:

- Area below the cyan line
- Area below green line
- Area below blue line (sorry, not very visible)
- Area above red line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHHBo.png)

What is the simplest way to shade off (grayed out or something similar) the constrained region? (as shown below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmITN.png)

```
clc
clear;
close all;

[X1,X2] = meshgrid(0:10:3000,0:10:6000);    
TEST = (33*X1 + 3*X2);                      
surf(X1,X2,TEST);   
hold on;                        

X2 = cell(4,1);             

X2{1,1} = 2*X1;           
X2{2,1} = 6000-2*X1;        
X2{3,1} = 9*X1;            
X2{4,1} = (X1*0)+1200;      

colour = cell(4,1);         

colour{1,1} = 'r';
colour{2,1} = 'g';
colour{3,1} = 'b';
colour{4,1} = 'c';

for i = 1:4
    TEST = (33*X1 + 3*X2{i,1});
    h=surf(X1,X2{i,1},TEST);
    set(h,'edgecolor',colour{i,1});
    set(h,'LineWidth',2)
    xlim([0 4000]);    
    ylim([0 7000]);   
    zlim([0 130000]);
    hold on;
end
```

Comment: You can call `surf` with a fourth input indicating the color of each section of the surface, i.e. `surf(X1, X2, TEST, COLOR)`.

Comment: I don't understand the black region you show on the second figure : it does not correspond to the quadrilateral region you describe by the "below,below,below, above" conditions. Besides, are you aware of the "patch" primitive  which is very handy in 3D: you just need for that to compute the vertices of your quadrilateral beforehand.